# I am getting the error while calling the path from below script and the error shown above

Tags: perl

I am getting the error while calling the path from below script and the error shown above.

./heartbeat.pl: my:  not found ./heartbeat.pl: $/: is not an identifier

```
my $ini_file = 'Search.ini';
local $/ = undef;
open( FH, $ini_file );
my $data = <FH>;
close(FH);
( my $search_item ) = $data =~ /<String_search>(.*?)<\/String_search>/;
( my $search_file ) = $data =~ /<File_search>(.*?)<\/File_search>/;
my $dir = $ARGV[0];

#my $dir = '/apps/scope/mst/scripts/heartbeat';
opendir( DIR, $dir );
my @files = grep {/($search_file)/} readdir(DIR);
closedir(DIR);
foreach (@files) {
    open( IN, "$dir\\$_" ) || die "$_ $!";
    my $file_data = <IN>;

    #print $file_data;
    print "FOUND:- $dir\\$_" if ( $file_data =~ /($search_item)/g );
    close(IN);
}
```

Comment: :Looks like you're reading XML there. Are you?

Comment: yup, to search the string and the files i used one ini file.

Comment: Then you really shouldn't use a regex. Treat XML as XML, not plain text.

Comment: please help me with the script i am not getting what your saying

Answer (score 1):

Call your script with `perl ./heartbeat.pl` or add `#!<path_to_perl>/perl` at the first line of your script

If you not do it, the system call you program as a shell command

Comment: And whilst you're at it - don't forget to add `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

Comment: i tried with these but still not working.

Comment: Do you still get the same errors?

Comment: @Arun What means "not working"?

Comment: ./heartbeat.pl: my:  not found
./heartbeat.pl: $/: is not an identifier     --- its showing this type of error.

Comment: @Arun Which suggestion you choose?

Comment: Those are exactly the errors you would get if you run this scriping a shell - either by copy-pasting, or using `/bin/sh` as your shell.

Comment: #!<path_to_perl>/perl------heartbeat.pl: line 2: my: command not found

Comment: you have changed <path_to_perl> with the correct path?

Comment: yes.............................

Comment: @Arun and if you call the script with `perl ./heartbeat.pl`?

Comment: i only used  ./heartbeat.pl.....now i used perl ./heartbeat.pl and its working now without any errors...If any error i will comment here.

Comment: How to execute the script step by step ? is there any specific command ?

Comment: @Arun Maybe tis helps: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html

Comment: The looks like you have an error in your path if you use this `#!<path_to_perl>/perl`

Comment: i am checking out Jens.